# select one textview and change its color at the same time out of 4 textviews

Tags: java, android

I have 4 textviews, out of 4 textviews, I have to select **anyone** from the 4 textviews, and also I have to change the background color(green) of the textview at the same time to highlight it.
Every textview  uses custom drawable background.

This is textview xml:

```
       <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_55sdp"
            style="@style/ChoosePlan"
           android:background="@drawable/choose_plan_bg"
            android:text="@string/part_time_monthly"
           />
```

That means

```
setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.color.green));
```

will not work.

So I tried like this:

```
     private void changeColor()
    {
    Drawable tempDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_plan_bg);
    LayerDrawable bubble = (LayerDrawable) tempDrawable; //(cast to root element in xml)
    GradientDrawable solidColor = (GradientDrawable) bubble.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.outerRectangle);
    solidColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
    textview1.setBackground(tempDrawable);
    textview1.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
   }
```

and onClick Event I call the above method:

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.tv_partTimeMonthly:
            changeColor();
            checkDoneBtnVisibile();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_partTimeAnnually:
            checkDoneBtnVisibile();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_fullTimeMonthly:
            checkDoneBtnVisibile();
            break;
        case R.id.tv_fullTimeAnually:
            checkDoneBtnVisibile();
            break;
        case R.id.iv_back_button:
            finish();
            break;
    }
    }
```

P.S: Have to use Textview(No ImageView)

I got stuck to it. Can you please help me out to move me forward.

Thanks in Advance

Sharing the Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: So what exactly is the problem that you are facing right now? What is the result of this code?

Comment: @skbrhmn  my code wont working what i need. My point is to select anyone textview at a time out of the 4 textviews

Comment: I meant is the app crashing or is it just not doing what you want? Do you mean to say that when you touch a textView, you want 'only' that textView to change colour and the others to revert back to the `choose_plan_bg` background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only updating `textview1` in your `changeColour()` method. If you just want to highlight 'only' one textView that is pressed at any time, then you may try something like the following.

First, I made a method that takes a textView as its argument that changes its background back to `choose_plan_bg`. Specify wherever your background is located in drawable.

```
private void changeColorBack(TextView textView)
{
      textView.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_plan_bg))
}
```

Similarly, the changeColour method:

```
private void changeColor(TextView textView)
{
Drawable tempDrawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.choose_plan_bg);
LayerDrawable bubble = (LayerDrawable) tempDrawable; //(cast to root element in xml)
GradientDrawable solidColor = (GradientDrawable) bubble.findDrawableByLayerId(R.id.outerRectangle);
solidColor.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.green));
textView.setBackground(tempDrawable);
textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));


}
```

Next, create a distinct `OnClickListener` and set the textViews to this listener:

```
View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            changeColorBack(textView1);
            changeColorBack(textView2);
            changeColorBack(textView3);
            changeColorBack(textView4);
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.textView1:
                    changeColor(textView1);
                    break;
                case R.id.textView2:
                    changeColor(textView2);
                    break;
                case R.id.textView3:
                    changeColor(textView3);
                    break;
                case R.id.textView4:
                    changeColor(textView4);
            }

        }
    };

    textView1.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView2.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView3.setOnClickListener(listener);
    textView4.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

This selects only the textView that is pressed and unselects anyone other textView.

Comment: what is outerRecatngle